# How to debug on Android device via WI-FI

Tags: android, debugging, firemonkey

I am trying to add an android device via WIFI, following the procedure found on Rad Studio documentation. The procedure seams to be completed, but I cannot see the device on the devices list, and also it does not appear on as a Target in the project. The next image show how the device was successfully added:

```
C:\RAD\23.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-23.0.51511.6924\platform-tools>adb pair 192.168.1.192:39951
Enter pairing code: 352975
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
Successfully paired to 192.168.1.192:39951 [guid=adb-RF8M92DS70T-xoYbWj]

C:\RAD\23.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-23.0.51511.6924\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached

C:\RAD\23.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2525-23.0.51511.6924\platform-tools>
```

Thank you for andy advise, and best regards!

Dany